# I can't login as Pi anymore

Tags: login

I've got a Pi book. Since last time I logged in, a new thing appears which asks me to enter username and password. It's called default xsession. This was already weird because it didn't happen before. If I try to login as Pi, blackscreen appears with a square colour (little rainbow in the corner) and I am in the login screen again. If I login as root everything works.

Comment: What book? What have you done? The devil is in the details.

Comment: Im german so yeah :D I mean ill probably just create a new acc. but just wanted to know why suddenly this Default X Session appears Book is that one: https://shop.heise.de/katalog/raspberry-pi-8

Comment: Is "the square color thingy" full screen (i.e., it's rebooting), or is it a littler rainbow one in the corner?

Comment: little rainbow in the corner

Answer (score 4):

Not enough reputation to comment, but the little rainbow in the corner is the pi telling you it doesn't have enough power. Check / change your power supply. Not sure if that will solve the problem, but it will at least avoid another one.

See [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=82373) for information on the warnings.